# own mp3 player from Android to BlackBerry

Tags: android, blackberry, blackberry-simulator

I'm trying to make an Android app written in Java, to work on Playbook too. Application is basically an mp3 player and I'm usimg MediaPlayer class. In the simulator I can't hear the sounds and I don't know why.

The problem is that I don't have access to a PlayBook device.

Do you know where/how can I find the problem? Is it possible that my application to work on the real devices even if in the simulator I can't hear the sounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now, I just had to modify the sound volume on the PlayBook simulator. It was on 80%, now is on 100%. I will investigate to see if this is the only cause.

Anyway, it works now.